# mysql custom order by with mixed data types

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In the following mysql query I'm using a custom order by statement so I can display various sizes in a specific order instead of alphabetical:

```
select distinct size 
from product p left join productsizes ps 
             on p.productcode = ps.size_prodcode 
order by field(size, 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL')
```

In cases where some products also have numeric sizes, how do I write the order by so that it places the numeric sizes in an ascending order along with the custom order?

An example of the desired output:

> 30, 32, 34, S, M, L

or

> S, M, L, 30, 32, 34

Comment: doing a very ugly `case` might work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns `0` when the search string is not found.  Therefore:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(size, 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'), size
```

Comment: Very cool answer. An innovative usage of `FIELD()` to separate strings and numbers

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN sizes REGEXP '(\d)+' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC,
         field(sizes, 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try use an enum field with all your sizes in it. It will maintain its sort order.

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
  ...
  size ENUM ('30', '32', '34', 'S', 'M', 'L')
  ...
);
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
  ...
  size ENUM ('S', 'M', 'L', '30', '32', '34')
  ...
);
```

Comment: But what happens when data is added to this table? How does one update the sorting order?