# Symfony2 doctrine custom function

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I like to add a custom function to doctrine.

I need to add a mysql **Field** function to be able to order by size like here:
[mysql custom order by with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454715/mysql-custom-order-by-with-mixed-data-types)

So I use this as exemple: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Field.php

and try to add it to Symfony2 like that: http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

When I do:

```
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy("FIELD(size, 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'), size, length", 'ASC');
```

I always get the error:
`Error: Expected end of string, got '('`

Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use DQL functions within `ORDER BY` clause. You must select the result of `FIELD()` function into hidden field and sort results using that field:

```
 SELECT ..., FIELD(size, ...) AS HIDDEN sizeOrder
 FROM ...
 ORDER BY sizeOrder
```

`sizeOrder` field won't affect your results as it won't be even hydrated.